# Revamp the requirements for commenting and not just posting

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**If you need to, just skip to the bottom paragraph, and if you feel up to it, then read the rest.**
This is no discussion on downvoting, going off-topic, or anything similar.
All of these questions like "Why did my post get labeled as off-topic?".
I am brand new here and my eyes are already bleeding from all of those posts.
Yes, I got here because I'm on hold for being off-topic.
Yes, I read what is considered off-topic.
 Do I care that I got labeled as off-topic? No. What I care about is how the people that responded to the question only offered the solution of "you compared a  boolean instead of using `!check`."  and "remove the conversion from String to int" even though it is required for the program to run and assumed that it would run just fine. I said in my post that that was not what was messing it up as it had worked previously with no problems with the same code.

Literally, all they did was offer that as the solution and instantly close the thread for being a typo. That is helpful to no one.
Then when you go to discuss it with them to figure out a real solution that might work they do not continue to help and assume that you're an idiot.

That in my eyes is what is possibly wrong with SO. There are hundreds of threads on how to post a question. I get that, read them all, edited my question to include all of the guidelines because I'm not a noob when it comes to Q&A forums like this.
But when I help someone on sites like these, I copy their code and compile it myself and see what's wrong, I don't just haphazardly offer solutions that make no sense, which I see all too often. Do I expect everyone to do that to everyone's questions? No. What I do expect is for people to actually try and answer the question and see if it was just a simple mistake instead of blowing it off.  Do I expect people to get annoyed and close a question when it is just a typo? Heck yes. Review your code man, this is for people that legitimately need help and have found none elsewhere. I've always respected SO because it is clear, cut, dry, logical, and has a decent community. It's just some of the people here are hot on their little flag buttons. Also, why completely remove a post if it gets marked as off-topic when there are so many that are on-topic but just don't have good wording?

As for the question: Why are there no criteria for posting a comment or answer to a question?
Such as not assuming that the "solution" was the answer (unless it's just that obvious) and possibly following up and if it was that simple **then** mark it as closed.
Being a feature request, yay or nay: Commenting regulations.
Another: Deprecated posts page. For the off-topic posts to have a final chance to be worded differently. (Because it's crappy to have a post completely crapped on when you sign up just to ask it, people get pretty emotional over this stuff.)

Comment: I don't understand what is so aggravating about receiving an answer to your problem. Both of the problems pointed out in [EJP's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059898/java-while-loop-breaking-before-execution#comment65469478_39059898) are legitimate, and the first one is causing your `RuntimeException`. Perhaps you should try that out before complaining that everyone is useless to you.

Comment: I've tried that as I mentioned in the post. I'm not aggravated about receiving an answer, I'm aggravated about people assuming that the answer they provided is the right one and close the thread because it seems simple. I never said that anyone was useless. The aggrevation is from ChiefTwoPencil's comment

Comment: I think you should double-check that you aren't making any mistakes on your end. Both of those *are* problems with your code. They would stop it from working correctly. If those fixes don't solve your problem, there's another problem that isn't being described well enough in your question.

Comment: That was all of the program code I have. I did try both solutions. I wouldn't lash out without trying them that would be completely illogical and a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: "Why are there no criteria for posting a comment or answer to a question?" I have a better one, hear me, maybe I'm crazy, but how about we set a criteria for posting questions?

Comment: Because we already have that @Braiam

Comment: I posted a comment in SOCVR chat [link](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32402736#32402736) to get your question quickly closed. If we closed your question errantly we are more than pleased to reopen it

Comment: @Drew, it was solved. Sad I can't mark it as answered as hichris123 sat down and took the time to help. I noticed the link in the chat, like I said in the post here, I am not angered by the fact that it was closed. I was aggravated by the quick assumptions that I made a simple typo, I'm more of the patient sit down and actually review the stuff guy.

Comment: Patrick, you said *... and assume that you're an idiot* ... on the contrary for me at least. And those are some Java heavies that reviewed it.

Comment: I voted to reopen. If others join, you and hichris can give it a happier ending.

Comment: I would vote to reopen, if the typos in the code were fixed and the question was edited to remove noise and focus on the actual problem and error. As it is, it still needs work

Comment: For the record people do make quick assumptions about typo's when all the ducks are lined up suggesting it. We review, what, over 200 questions a day. Stuff around here doesn't close too easily. If people want to bash SO on reddit or somewhere that it is a closing frenzy, well gosh, I must be frequenting a much different SO in a parallel universe. One has to nearly go out of their way to their question closed around here. When I offer a solution, I almost always test it before submitting (like my last answer). But I should not feel like I need to drag your code thru IntelliJ to close it.

Comment: @TinyGiant Just close them both. Although I still think it would be nice to have some sort of reg. on commenting and deprecated posts. Or at least have a site dedicated to non-pro gander like this that still has the reputation. Like I said, I've been on these kinds of forums for 7+ years, that's usually the big problem, the people offering the first solution see the first error and say that that's it.

Comment: @Drew I know the feeling. There was a FB group that I moderated for a while and I had to stop.

Comment: The regulations on comments that you're asking for are unenforceable and really don't make much sense. It isn't the comments that close your questions, it is the users who have enough reputation to cast close votes reviewing your question and deeming it off-topic. Oh, and Stack Overflow is not a forum, nor a discussion site, it is a repository of Questions and Answers. Comments technically hold no lasting value here so they don't count as real things.

Comment: Well it's hard to see that it's a repository of Questions and Answers when something can be considered off-topic from its relatable content. It begs the statement: if you don't like it, move on and answer something else. If you can help, then answer it and close. Which obviously that creates more work for mods, if only things weren't so overboard.

Comment: Off topic includes many things. One being Typo (incl resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers) and Tool Rec (including give me a tutorial and, to me, be my tutor). They are all subjective. If your question wasn't closed for Typo, it could have fallen to Unclear. We don't get paid to do this Patrick. No free pizza deliveries. We try to make the stack a better place. Sorry you got your feelings hurt. But I am sure of this: if you stick around, you will enjoy your Java and other contributions here. And learn from others.

Comment: It isn't that we don't like it, it is that it is off-topic. This is a community moderated site, we all pitch in to keep the site clean, which means downvoting, voting to close, and voting to delete questions which are off-topic.

Comment: I'd like to jump in here and say that my first comment likely prompted the close vote, and honestly, I was felt like I was helping by pointing out the issue stated in the question. The while loop was working incorrectly because the conditional did not appear to be written correctly. Regarding the RuntimeException, re-writing that conditional would not have caused that, so if you commented saying "oh, I did make a typo, but now I get this stacktrace" and had edited the question to include it, then it likely would not have been closed.

Comment: And as you've stated, you copyright code from answers. Sure, you'll need to understand in what context the code needs used in your source code, but it's largely different for questions. Sure, it's bad form to skip the text and look at the code, but reading a long description just to identify the root problem gets tiresome for question after question. It is the title that attracts people to the question. I saw something like  "while loop skipping", so immediate thought would be "something is wrong with the condition". Sure enough, it looked like there was

Comment: And now, after reading the solution on that post, it would appear the problem statement of the post was not clearly written from the start. I did help resolve the while loop problem, so then the secondary problem to that was a compilation error for incorrect parameters to the method. Yes, you stated you're learning and what not, but the first thing you need to check when something like that happens is the expected parameter types. Just check the types - don't try to read into what /how they are used until yours match what is expected.

Answer (score 12):

TLDR at the bottom.

This answer is a little convoluted, as it actually attempts to address the point in the question.

### Addressing Why Your Question Was Closed

Firstly, as one of the people who closed the question. I left no comment, I voted to close *it as being not reproducible*, it possibly could be closed as *Unclear* or:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

The close reason is less important than the fact it was closed. Either way, no one can reproduce your issue as you have not provided all the code pertaining to the problem.

You state [in your SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059898/java-while-loop-breaking-before-execution-username-verify-through-joptionpane):

> It worked the first time through but after that, it has not worked since. I have not altered any of the code except to add another statement in the loop (it wasn't working even before then) so the new statement may be wrong.
>   That's not my concern.
>   My question is why would it not execute even though it executed flawlessly before? I have already changed the returns to breaks to see if that would solve it but it did not. I'm stuck.

You don't tell us what the new statement is, or how you changed the returns. So we never see the code in the form where it worked.

You say that's not your concern, that a statement may not be working, well if it's breaking the code, then that's a concern.

For the record, many people make off topic posts (both questions and answers) when they first start here, and it's the community feedback that teaches us how to improve them, to be a good fit for the community.

### Addressing The Points In Your Question

> Do I expect everyone to do that to everyone's questions? No. What I do expect is for people to actually try and answer the question and see if it was just a simple mistake instead of blowing it off.
>
> Do I expect people to get annoyed and close a question when it is just a typo? Heck yes. Review your code man, this is for people that legitimately need help and have found none elsewhere.

Please do the same and post a clear question, with a clear problem statement and the steps taken from when your code was working to where it was broken.

> I've always respected SO because it is clear, cut, dry, logical, and has a decent community. It's just some of the people here are hot on their little flag buttons.

The people here who are "hot on their little flag buttons" are the same people who made comments and answer questions and are attempting to give you a clear cut, dry and logical response to both your questions on the main site and here. Although your question here is disorganised and contains multiple questions and in part is insulting to the community.

*As a side bar, complimenting the site and wrapping it up with an insult doesn't count as a compliment.*

> Also, why completely remove a post if it gets marked as off-topic when there are so many that are on-topic but just don't have good wording?

If a post is on topic, it won't be removed. If it's wording is not clear, it may not be on topic. Sometimes mistakes are made, hence most actions are reversible.

On one hand you complain, at length about the comments and then you ask for a feature request to have users leave comments and answers.

> Why are there no criteria for posting a comment or answer to a question?

Both comments and an answer were posted offering  solutions to your problem.

[image]

**TLDR**

If the community offers you help with a question that is unclear, and you don't get the answer you were looking for, I suggest you have a look at the question, not the community. People here, mostly, act in good faith, in both moderating the content, and when posting comments and answers. It is offensive to write a long discourse of the failings of the site, for people who have added value to the site, from a person who has been a member for one day and contributed very little, but issued many complaints.

Comment: My apologies for sounding insulting @yvette and the rest. I definitely was not aiming for that. You're right, it's a learning experience. To be fair on my account, the answer was deleted before I got a chance to respond to it, that's what primarily got to me. Thank you for clarifying everything, you and the others. I won't jump the gun next time

Comment: @PatrickFinnegan you're most welcome. We all have our moments and I will admit it can be a tough site to start on. There's a lot of content posted daily and it is moderated to try and keep content on topic. Don't give up, and if you look at most user's histories, you will see dud posts (mine included).

Comment: Went ahead and voted to delete since I deserve a Darwin Award from it. This one should be kept as it is a good way to show noobs how to handle things. I don't have enough rep. But I've been in there a few times because some of the posts y'all go through is hilarious. (No offense)

Comment: @PatrickFinnegan you're most welcome, we also joke a lot. we can get serious and stressed. when you have more rep you can come in and chat. When you get even more you can help us vote on stuff ;)